# Queue for Booleans in C

Tags: c, queue

This is my queue.h

```
#define MAX_SIZE 40

void queueInit(void);
Bool queuePeek(void);
Bool queueIsEmpty(void);
Bool queueIsFull(void);
int queueSize(void);
void enqueue(Bool data);
Bool dequeue(void);
```

and this is the implementation :

```
#include "queue.h"

static char head, tail, itemCnt;
static Bool buffer[MAX_SIZE];

void queueInit(void)
{
    head = 0;
    tail = -1;
    itemCnt = 0;
}

Bool queuePeek(void)
{
    return buffer[head];
}

Bool queueIsEmpty(void) {
   return itemCnt == 0;
}

Bool queueIsFull(void) {
   return itemCnt == MAX_SIZE;
}

int queueSize(void) {
   return itemCnt;
}

void enqueue(Bool data)
{
       if(!isFull()) {

          if(tail == MAX_SIZE-1) {
             tail = -1;
          }

          buffer[++tail] = data;
          itemCnt++;
       }

}


Bool dequeue(void)
{
     Bool data = buffer[head++];

       if(head == MAX_SIZE) {
          head = 0;
       }

       itemCnt--;
       return data;
}
```

Now I try to call the functions in my main.c

`queueInit();`

After that I get the error "conflicting types for 'queueInit()'.
Can you help me to sort out the problem ?

Thanks,

Christian

Comment: Did you enclose `queueInit();` inside `int main(void)`?

Comment: What's in main.c?

Comment: The posted code does **not** generate the said error. Please, post the actual code.

Comment: Also notice that the code calls `isFull` but there is no such function. There is however a `queueIsFull` function. Again it just shows that the posted code doesn't match the actual code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You don't show the code with `main()` unless I'm missing something.  How are we to help you debug the code we can't see?  Please read up on how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]) — and sometime read the [About] and [Ask] pages too.  It sounds a bit as if you're including either `queue.h` or perhaps `queue.c` into the file containing `main()`, but after you've called `queueInit()`.  You also probably aren't compiling with enough warnings enabled.

Comment: timrau was right, i was not calling the init function inside the main() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using GCC `gcc queue.c -Wall -std=c11 -c queue` I had the following problems:

1. unknown type name 'Bool'
2. array subscript has type 'char'
3. implicit declaration of function 'isFull'

The first issue can be solved with a `typedef _Bool Bool`, whereas the type of the static variables should perhaps be changed to `int` and the function name changed to match the header declaration.